# Eclipse highlight matching parenthesis

Tags: eclipse

I see plenty of posts about matching brackets, however not so much love for parenthesis. In Eclipse how do I get matching parenthesis to highlight? I'm working in java and groovy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open any Java file in Java editor inside eclipse. Put caret just after opening or closing parenthesis. You can see the corresponding matching parenthesis highlighted, but unfortunately the default highlight background and foreground colors are not good.

So change this color in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Appearance color option > Matching brackets highlight`

Check this [Bracketeer plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-java-jdt#group-screenshots) which has many other features along with showing matching brackets. But it works for only C/C++ or Java code not for groovy.