# Show line of matching brace for Java in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

So, let's say I select a closing brace. I want eclipse to not only highlight the matching opening brace, I want it to show me its whole line on the top of my editor, no matter how higher up it is. I'm sure I've seen it on some other IDE, is it possible to do on Eclipse? For example, if it's a closing brace for an if statement, I want to see the opening of this if to see its condition. This could also apply to methods, loops, etc.

If not showing the whole line, I would at least like to highlight the whole line with a color that stands out, so that I can find it easier through scrolling. I know I can jump there with Ctrl+Shift+P, but it's not always practical.

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482388/eclipse-highlight-matching-parenthesis

Comment: @e.g78 This plugin is not supported by my version of Eclipse (4.14).