# Is there a way to color-code parentheses in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Is there a way to color-code matching parentheses in Eclipse? I am looking for a way to have matching parentheses be a different color when nested, similar to how Excel does it.

Comment: Possibly related: [Eclipse highlight matching parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43482388)

Answer (score 2):

You can install the ["Bracketeer for Java (JDT)"](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-java-jdt#group-details) plugin from the marketplace. It highlights brackets depending on what you select in different greys (or red, in case a bracket is not matched):

[image]

Curly brackets as well:

[image]

Comment: To install this pluggin use the following url: http://chookapp.github.io/ChookappUpdateSite/ found it at: https:/github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer/issues/25. The one in eclipse is the old one.